# CHMOD 777 specific file extensions in Terminal

Tags: regex, macos, terminal, chmod

I am trying to CHMOD 777 all .doc files on my Mac.  Is there is a way through Terminal that I could do this?

__

Thanks for the responses.  I thought this was the way to change permissions on Word doc files.  I have 2 users on Mac make that share a folder.  But when one creates a doc file the other just has read permissions. I want both of them to have this, or everyone.  It doesn'tmatter. I also want to go back and retroactively make all the past docs, some of which user A has read&write permissions, and some of which user B has read&write permissions for, read&writeable by both of them. Is there another way to do this?  From what I can tell, this is a Mac permissions issue, nothing in Word. I thought CHMOD 777 in terminal was the way to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to set them all to mode 777? .doc files aren't executable, so granting execute permissions to them doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `xargs` or the `-exec` option of `find`.

```
/home/erjablow> find . -name "*.doc" | xargs -n 3 chmod a+rwx
                # Find the names of all "doc" files beneath the current directory.
                # Gather them up 3 at a time, and execute
                # chmod a+rwx file1 file2 file3
                # on each set.
```

Now, `find` is a nasty utility, and hard to use. It can do ridiculous things, and one misspelling can ruin one's day.

Why do you want to make all doc files unprotected?

Comment: Why `-n 3`? Just let `xargs` feed as many arguments as it can to `chmod`. Also, I think a Mac is likely to have files or directories with spaces in their names; your command could apply the `chmod` to files or directories you don't mean it to.

Comment: Just doing 1 a a time leads to too many shells.  I tend to be cautious about numbers of arguments.  Perhaps that's silly. I'm not sure how to correctly quote the arguments in xargs.

Comment: In this case, I'd just drop the `-n 3` and trust `xargs` not to cause an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous response that `find` is nasty.  And piping it to another utility can be tricky.  If I had to do this, I'd specify the file type and use find's `exec` function instead of xargs.

`find / -x -type f -iname *.doc \-exec chmod 777 {} \;`

`-x` will search only the local Macintosh HD and exclude any mounted volumes

You may want to consider other criteria to refine the search, like a different starting point or excluding particular folders and/or file extensions

`find / -x find / -not \( -path "*/some_sub-folder*" -or -path "*/some_other_sub-folder*" \) -type f \( -iname *.doc -or -iname *.docx \) \-exec chmod 777 {} \;`

Or if you're set on using `find|xargs`, you should probably try `-print` instead of `-print0` so that each file is returned as a separate line.  That could fix it as well.

Either way, backup before doing this and test carefully.  Good luck, HTH.

Comment: This could cause serious problems if any files or directories have spaces in their names.

Comment: I disagree.  I tried an identical test on files with spaces in the names and it worked just fine.  The thing is that the -exec primary correctly parses the spaces within the curly braces.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I was thinking of `find ... -print | xargs ...`, which does have problems with spaces (the solution is `find ... -print0 | xargs -0`). But that's not what you're doing. The `find | xargs` approach does avoid invoking the `chmod` command once for each file, but that's probably not a major concern. (My real concern is that a system-wide `chmod 777` is likely to be a really bad idea in the first place, and the OP hasn't explained why he wants to do it.)

Comment: I agree completely about it, but it's not my machine!  I'm just solving for fun. ;-)  Also, I modified my answer after noticing the OP is using `print0`.  His/her method might work with `-print` (no zero).

Comment: Why would `-print` work better than `-print0`? The OP didn't mention using `-print0`; that's from my answer, and it's necessary (if you use `xargs`) to avoid problems with directories and files with spaces in their names.

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

If you *really* want to do this:

```
find / -x -name `*.doc` -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

I have not tested this. I don't guarantee that the Mac versions of the `find` and `xargs` commands support all these options; I'm used to the GNU findutils versions that are common on Linux systems.

The `find` command starts at the root directory, limiting itself (`-x`) to the current filesystem, selects files whose names end in `.doc`, and prints them separated by null characters. The latter is necessary in case you have files or directories whose names contain spaces. The `-x` option is equivalent to the `-xdev` option in some other versions of `find`.

If you want to match files whose names in in `.Doc`, `.DOC`, etc., use `-iname '*.doc'` rather than `-name '*.doc'`.

The `xargs` command takes this null-delimited list of files and executes `chmod 777` on each of them, breaking the list into chunks that won't overflow `chmod`'s command line.

Let me emphasize again that:

1. I have not tested the above command. I don't currently have access to a MacOS system; I've just read the relevant man pages online. If you want to do a dry run, replace `xargs` by `echo xargs`; it will print the commands that it would execute (expect a lot of output with very long lines). Or replace `xargs` by `xargs -n 1 echo` to produce one line for each file.
2. Doing this in the first place is a bad idea. `777` gives read, write, and execute permission to every user on the system. `.doc` files are not executables; giving them execute permission makes no sense on a Unix-like system. `644` is likely to be a more sensible value (read/write for the owner, read-only for everyone else).